# MySQL 5.6 Declare Issue

Tags: mysql

Let's see if I can edit this and put the whole procedure in.

I am trying to convert an Oracle database to MySQL. I have all the tables, keys, indexes, and views converted. I now need to convert a stored procedure to MySQL.

I have most of it done, and there is only one hang up on my code:

```
set dns1_tmp = X.X.X.X;
SET dns2_tmp = X.X.X.X;
```

This gives me an error of 1064 Syntax Error: Missing semicolon

I have tested the rest of my procedure, and it works fine. It creates it, runs it, and retrieves data from it, but only if I remove those two lines.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Whole stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

USE `TEST`//

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `proc_IN`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_IN`
(IN DNIS VARCHAR(20),
IN MSISDN VARCHAR(20),
IN AVPAIR1 VARCHAR(20),
IN AVPAIR2 VARCHAR(20),
IN GROUPID VARCHAR(20),
OUT DNS1 VARCHAR(15),
OUT DNS2 VARCHAR(15),
OUT AUTHSTAT VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
declare dns1_tmp varchar(15);
declare dns2_tmp varchar(15);
set dns1_tmp = X.X.X.X;
SET dns2_tmp = X.X.X.X;
DECLARE avpair1_tmp varchar(15);
DECLARE avpair2_tmp varchar(15);
DECLARE grpid_tmp varchar(15);

DECLARE C_USER CURSOR FOR SELECT AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1, DNS2, GROUPID FROM GRP, ALLMEMBER WHERE ALLMEMBER.GROUPID=GRP.GROUPID
    UNION
    SELECT AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1, DNS2, GROUPID FROM GRP; 
OPEN C_USER;
FETCH C_USER INTO AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1, DNS2, GROUPID;
LOOP
    FETCH C_USER INTO avpair1_tmp, avpair2_tmp, dns1_tmp, dns2_tmp, grpid_tmp;
    INSERT INTO duplog VALUES(DNIS, MSISDN, avpair1_tmp, avpair2_tmp, dns1_tmp,dns2_tmp, grpid_tmp, SYSDATE);
END LOOP;
IF C_USER%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO duplog VALUES(DNIS, MSISDN, AVPAIR1, AVPAIR2, DNS1,DNS2, GROUPID, SYSDATE);
            SET AUTHSTAT := 'ok';
        elseif C_USER%ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN
            SET AUTHSTAT := 'ok';
ELSE
            SET AUTHSTAT := NULL;
END IF;

CLOSE C_USER;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I have my DELIMITER BEGIN and END". Can you post the complete stored procedure?

Comment: I would have to piece it up

Comment: I can't submit it. Get an error of this is mostly code

Comment: I have a DELIMTER // at the top, and a BEGIN and an END

Comment: Okay, but what about `CREATE PROCEDURE...`?  That goes before `BEGIN` if you'er going to create a procedure... Also, it's not related to the error, but the user-defined variable `@dns1_tmp` is not the same variable as the declared stored program variable `dns_tmp1`.  You are declaring two variables that you're not actually using, and then you're using two different (un-typed) variables from a different scope.  Remove the `@` symbols to use the correct variables.

Comment: Yeah I do a CREATE PROCEDURE. I did figure out a way past the DECLARE issue, however doing SET @dns2_tmp := 'X.X.X.X'; has an error of SYNTAX ERROR: Missing end. I do have an END later on in the procedure

Comment: I've also tried with double quotes, without quotes, etc...

Comment: I have tried it this way:

    SET dns1_tmp = 12.127.17.72;
    SET dns2_tmp = 204.97.212.10;

I get a missing semicolon error